# Copying files from cab to folder

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to copy the files from .cab file to a normal folder. I don't have extract.exe on my Windows 7. And using xcopy /s .\file.cab .\extracts throws an error saying "Cannot perform a cyclic copy". I've googled the error, but found nothing applicable. The destination folder is empty, and otherwise it can only copy the .cab file but not the files within it. I want to copy all the files within .cab file into a folder. Can someone help? I want this to work on a client environment so I don't want to download any other tools, just command line if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of the following commands. Both should be included in your windows 7

```
expand file.cab .\extracts
extrac32 file.cab /L .\extracts
```

Comment: Expand can be used in PowerShell as well.